# WHM cgi scripts internal server error

Tags: cpanel, whm

I am getting `500 internal server error` during of running CGI scripts in `cgi-bin` folder, I checked everything and it seems everything are fine, please see below details

- I am using `WHM`
- Perl file permission is ok `/usr/bin/perl 755`
- `ExecCGI` is enabled in Apache Configuration in `WHM`
- `CGI Privilege` is enabled for user from `WHM` modify account area

I am really confused, what should I do?

Comment: You should look in the server logs to see what the error message is.

Comment: The error log..